# Is this generics example from Bruce Eckel's "Thinking in Java" wrong?

Tags: java, generics

I am reading the generics chapter in "Thinking in java". The program is there below.

```
public class GenericWriting {
    static <T> void writeExact(List<T> list, T item) {
        list.add(item);
    }
    static List<Apple> apples = new ArrayList<Apple>();
    static List<Fruit> fruit = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
    static void f1() {
        writeExact(apples, new Apple());
        // writeExact(fruit, new Apple()); // Error:------------------line 1
        // Incompatible types: found Fruit, required Apple
    }
    static <T> void writeWithWildcard(List<? super T> list, T item) {
        list.add(item);
    }
    static void f2() {
        writeWithWildcard(apples, new Apple());
        writeWithWildcard(fruit, new Apple());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) { f1(); f2(); }
}
```

Below it says "The writeExact( ) method uses an exact parameter type (no wildcards). In f1( ) you can see that this works fine—as long as you only put an Apple into a `List<Apple>`. However, writeExact( ) does not allow you to put an Apple into a `List<Fruit>`, even though you know that should be possible."

But when I uncomment the line 1 and execute it, it is working fine. Can anyone please help me where I went wrong?

Comment: if you want people to be able to read your code, be kind enough to use some indentation.

Comment: I think the only thing you've done wrong is choosing this book.

Comment: You can download the 4th edition of this book [here](http://www.saeedsh.com/resources/Thinking%20in%20Java%204th%20Ed.pdf), and this example is on page 486 (page 508 of the PDF). I've also looked at the 3rd edition, and this example is the same in that one as well.

Comment: Hi Chris, I am using 4th edition. Yes it is in 508 page.

Comment: Am I using the old version? this is the one latest available right? Can u plz tell

Answer (score 5):

> However, `writeExact( )` does not allow you to put an `Apple` into a `List<Fruit>`, even though you know that should be possible.

This is incorrect. `writeExact` can put an `Apple` in to a `List<Fruit>`. `<T>` is inferred to be `Fruit` and `Apple` (presumably) is a subtype of `Fruit`.

The book contains an error. I can confirm that this will compile as of **Java 5**, when generics were introduced.

Answer (score -1):

I think the author instead of the line 
`static List<Fruit> fruit = new ArrayList<Fruit>();`
wanted to write 
`static List<? extends Fruit> fruit = new ArrayList<Fruit>();`